# How to NOT scale an image in SVG

Tags: svg

So I have an image in SVG as follows:

```
<image id="svgBackground" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin" xlink:href="backgrounds.png"/>
```

I want the browser to show the image at the original size.  How do I do that?

Comment: Surely just drop the `width="100%"` and `height="100%"` and let the browser deal with it?

Comment: I have tried that but the image doesn't show up at all if I do that.

Comment: Can you demonstrate the problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [Tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/) or a similar site?

Comment: `preserveAspectRatio="none"` ?

Answer (score 3):

Specify the image's original size using "px" units: `width="150px" height="100px"` or whatever it ought to be.

If you omit `width` and/or `height` entirely, it defaults to zero and the image is not rendered.