# How to display SVG without any scaling

Tags: object, svg, scale

I have some code that generates diagrams in SVG.  I want to display those in a web page.   I want all the diagrams scaled at the original scale.  There are many diagrams of varying sizes.  The window I am displaying them in might change size, responsive to the browser size.  But I do not want the SVG to be scaled.  I want it to scroll instead.

I can ember the object tag in a div tag, and I can turn on the scroll bars for the div tag, but no matter what I do, the SVG is scaled to fit in the div.

If I knew the size of the image, I could force the canvas to be the same size.  Is there any way to just say: bring in the SVG and don't do any scaling?

This same question was [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059826/how-to-not-scale-an-image-in-svg) but no answer.

Here is a sample svg file:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    viewBox="0 0 1191 971" 
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <rect x="372" y="188" width="102" height="68" rx="10" 
        ry="10" style="stroke:blue"/>
    <svg x="372" y="188" width="102" height="68">
        <text>
            <tspan x="51" y="12">DTP</tspan>
        </text>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

But remember, this one is 1191x971 but others will be all different sizes.  I would like it to display without scaling, no matter the size of the SVG diagram dimensions.

Here i the div tag I am placing this in, and I am using AngularJS to place the URL value into the object tag.  In this case I am forcing the div to be 300x300, but that is because I want to test that the SVG is not scaled to this size.

```
<div style="height:300px;width:300px;overflow:scroll">
    <object type="image/svg+xml"  data="{{svgUrl}}">
    </object>
</div>
```

What I get with that is the 300x300 area appears with scroll bars, but the SVG image is scaled (shrunk) to fit in 300x300 area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it exists now, your SVG has been configured to be scaling/responsive.  This is because of two things.

1. It has a `viewBox`
2. It has no `width` or `height` defined, so those attributes default to "100%". Meaning 100% of its container.

If you want it to *not* scale, then you need give either the `<svg>`, or the `<object>`, a specific width.  For example, if you want it to be rendered at 1:1, you would need to give it the same width and height as the viewBox:

```
<svg width="1191" height="971"  ...>
```

or

```
<object width="1191" height="971"  ...>
```

If you are able to alter the original SVGs, then that would probably be the simplest solution.  Otherwise, you are going to need some JS. After the SVG has loaded, get a reference to the SVG element via the `contentDocument` property on the `<object>` element.  From there you can get the viewBox width and height. Then use those to update the `<object>` width and height.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I had the view box, but the trick was ALSO adding the width and height in the svg tag.  With that, everything stays scaled 1:1 with the original.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
    width="100%" height="100%"
```

As attributes in the enclosing **div** tag:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <div width="100%" height="100%">
   <svg style="background:plum" width="240px" height="120px"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >

   <polygon points="60,30 90,90 30,90">
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                      attributeType="XML"
                      type="rotate"
                      from="0 60 70"
                      to="360 60 70"
                      dur="10s"
                      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</polygon>
</svg>
</div>
```

With **svg** dimensions in pixels.

Comment: Nope. That does not work.  Putting 100% on a height and width normally means 'scale this to be the same as the containing frame' which is exactly the behavior I want to avoid.  I tested it:  whether there is width/height 100% or not, the SVG IN THE OBJECT TAG is always scaled to the size of the containing frame.  Putting the SVG inline in the page behaves very differently from putting a file reference in an OBJECT tag.